# Minimizing multi variable function while some variables of the function stay constant. The constant variable is a list of lists

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

i am fairly new to python and already encountered a quite complicated problem (well at least for me). I wanna minimize a function with multiple variables where one variable is a list of lists with data I gained from a simulation. This list should stay fixed while the programs optimizes the other two variables.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0acb424f7c6942329918430fb616c040

Here is my code so far in 3 different files. Simulation.py is the simulation which computes a list of lists. in Function.py contains my function "Gompertz" which I wanna minimize. As you can see it contains three variables. Into the first variable I wanna put my list ("deathlist") from the simulation. The other two variables I wanna optimize using the minimize function from Scipy.
Running the Program gives me following errors but I guess there is something wrong in general with the way I coded my solution. Any help would be appreciated :). (Don't worry about all the names containing death in the program. I am working on mortality data)

(Edit: I changed the boundary conditions to b = (0.001, 10))

Edit: To clarify The Optimize.py is the important part. The Simulation.py and the Function.py are just for context. My question here is how I can make the list into a constant variable in the optimization process while optimizing the other two variables. So in the Optimize.py file I put the boundary conditions for the list as b = (deathlist, deathlist) so it would stay constant. I am not sure if this is correct or not and if it is not correct how can I write this code differently.

````
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects
/untitled2/Test/Simulation.py", 
line 25, in <module> sol = minimize(Function.Gompertz, x0, method ='SlSQP',bounds = bnds, constraints 
= cons) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib
/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", 

line 458, in minimize constraints, callback=callback, **options) File "/Library
/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy
/optimize/slsqp.py", 
line 307, in _minimize_slsqp x = asfarray(x0).flatten() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", 
line 105, in asfarray return asarray(a, dtype=dtype) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", 
line 482, in asarray return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.```
````

Comment: Try to condense your code to only include the problematic part. This makes it easier to answer!

Comment: Well I am not really sure where the problem lies, thats why I divided the code into 3 files. The Simulation.py is not the problem so I could exclude it. I putted it there just for context. But the Optimize.py file is where I think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
 says that array element could not contain lists.

For giving `minimize()` constant values you should split arguments of your original function to the `(n,)` ndarray `x`  and all the other arguments. 
So the right code for giving the addditional constant arguments to your `minimize()`  function would be:

```
def Gompertz(x, consts):

    x1 = x[1]
    x2 = x[2]
    LF = 0

    for j in range (100):
        DEATH = consts[j]
        T = len(consts)
        for tau in range(T): """the length of the list gives the range of the loop"""
                lf_i = x1 * exp(x2 * tau - x1/x2 * (exp(x2 * tau)-1))
                a = DEATH[tau]
                LF += lf_i ** a   """the values from the list are used here as a power of the valute lf_i """
return -LF
```

```
deathlist = Function.Simulation()
x0 = [1,1]

sol = minimize(Function.Gompertz, x0, args=(deathlist,) method ='SlSQP',bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
print (sol)
```